# Is there a way to pass several arguments using navigation in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a component that uses navigation when clicked to change screens. When I do so, I want to be able to pass a couple of arguments using navigation.navigate.

Card Component

```
const Card = props => {
    return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={() => props.nav.navigate('ActivityScreen', {activityTitle: 'this is not working >:(', activityID: props.id})}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
            <View style={styles.insideCardView}>
                <Text>More Text</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

New Screen (that i want my info on)

```
import React from 'react';
import  {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const ActivityScreen = props => {
    return (<View style={styles.header}>
        <Text>This is the Avtivity page</Text>
        {
            //This does not work, gives no error, just blank
        }
        <Text>{props.activityTitle}</Text>
        <Text>{props.activityID}</Text>
    
    </View>);
}
```

Is this suppose to work? And if so, is this the most effective way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access it using `props.route.params.yourParamName`. So write your code as following :

```js
import React from 'react';
import  {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const ActivityScreen = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Text>This is the Avtivity page</Text>
      {
          //This does not work, gives no error, just blank
      }
      <Text>{props.route.params.activityTitle}</Text>
      <Text>{props.route.params..activityID}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```